# Why are these CIDR causing errors with Snowflake Network Policy?

Tags: ip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cidr

Any ideas why the below IP addresses are saying they are invalid with Snowflake's Network Policy? It seems [they support CIDR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#cidr-notation).
[image: IP Addresses with issues]

Comment: They all are valid from a mask perspective. What output/feedback are you getting that they are not good for CIDR reasons?

Comment: The error reads `Invalid IPv4 address` for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bug in snowflake, response from their team:

> The behavior which you are seeing is failing from Snowsight. This is
> already identified and is currently under review.
>
> Please make a note of the internal tracking number: SNOW-549872.
>
> I am afraid that I do not have an ETA for the fix yet.

Edit on 2022/02/28: This issue in Snowsight is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

the first two are [Tableau public addresses](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_tableau_online_ip_authorization.htm).

| Host Name (Instance) | Site Location | IP Address or Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| prod-useast-a.online.tableau.com | US East - Virginia | 3.219.176.16/28 |
| prod-useast-b.online.tableau.com | US East - Virginia | 3.219.176.16/28 |

The third is fivetran..

https://fivetran.com/docs/getting-started/ips

and the last is redshift.

But I suspect you know that.. it could be that they have a "block" block, to stop people foot gunning them selves.

I would ask a support question. because it should be valid

Answer (score 2):

Using the classic console did the trick for us

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).